# Упаковщик спрайтов в Unity3D 5.4

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, движок, спрайт

Мне не удается запустить [упаковщик спрайтов (Sprite Packer)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/SpritePacker.html) в Unity3D 5.4.1.
Делаю по инструкции из документации:

- Включил упаковщик в настройках  *Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor* (*Always Enabled*)
- Создал в каталог *Assets -> Sprites* в который сложил все картинки
- Картинки под спрайты одного размера, боле того - они квадратные
- Выделил все будущие спрайты в папке
- Задал все следующие параметры:

  - *Texture Type -> Sprite (2D and UI)*
  - *Packing Tag -> SpriteItem*
  - *Filter Mode -> Point (no filter)*
  - *Default Max Size -> 2048*
  - *Format -> Truecolor*
- Открываю упаковщик *Window -> Sprite Packer* и нажимаю *Pack*

В результате ничего не получаю...
Упаковщик в принципе недоступен в бесплатной редакции Personal или я что-то не настроил?

Comment: судя по написанному тут https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-free-and-sprite-packing.211028/   да в pro только.  можно попробовать использовать [TexturePacker Free](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/8905)  и [TexturePacker Importer](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/16641)

Comment: Я видел эту тему, однако была у меня надежда, что ситуация за это время изменилась. Что же, жаль что нет. А за плагины спасибо.